# Arrange given list of integers to get least number using merge sort in python

Tags: python-2.7, sorting, merge

Suppose my given array is [9,89,10005,77987] , I have used custom comparison in merge sort algo.I want to get [10005,77987,89,9] which can be later used to get least number 1000577987899 after arranging numbers.I am using random.randint(0,100) to generate an array.
My input: `[70, 73, 85, 60, 76]`
My output:

```
before: [70, 73, 85, 60, 76]
['70', '73', '85', '60', '76']
splitting the array ['70', '73', '85', '60', '76']
splitting the array ['70', '73']
merging ['70', '73']
splitting the array ['85', '60', '76']
splitting the array ['60', '76']
merging ['60', '76']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "venture.py", line 66, in <module>
mergeSort(b)
  File "venture.py", line 33, in mergeSort   
mergeSort(righthalf) #the recursive call after splitting
  File "venture.py", line 41, in mergeSort
if  int(lefthalf[i])*10**len(righthalf[j])+int(righthalf[j]) < int(righthalf[j])*10**len(lefthalf[i])+int(lefthalf[j]): #custom_comparison
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My code:

```
import random

def mergeSort(alist):
    if len(alist)>1:
        print "splitting the array",alist
        mid = len(alist)//2  #the floor div
        lefthalf = alist[:mid]
        righthalf = alist[mid:]
        mergeSort(lefthalf)  #the recursive call after splitting
        mergeSort(righthalf) #the recursive call after splitting

        i=0
        j=0
        k=0


        while i < len(lefthalf) and j < len(righthalf):
            if  int(lefthalf[i])*10**len(righthalf[j])+int(righthalf[j]) < int(righthalf[j])*10**len(lefthalf[i])+int(lefthalf[j]): #custom comparison
                alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
                i=i+1
            else:
                alist[k]=righthalf[j]
                j=j+1
            k=k+1

        while i < len(lefthalf):  #to be used when index j is out of range of len(righthalf)
            alist[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i=i+1
            k=k+1

        while j < len(righthalf): #to be used when index i is out of range of len(lefthalf)
            alist[k]=righthalf[j]
            j=j+1
            k=k+1
        print "merging",alist



a = [random.randint(0,100) for c in range(5)]
print "before:",a
b = map(str, a)
print b
mergeSort(b)
print "new :",b
```

Why is the error occurring? **The same code works with regular comparison**:`if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:` .I just changed **if condition** to `if  int(lefthalf[i])*10**len(righthalf[j])+int(righthalf[j]) < int(righthalf[j])*10**len(lefthalf[i])+int(lefthalf[j]): #custom comparison`.
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the `righthalf` and `lefthalf` will be of different lengths if the original list (`alist`) is odd.

Your while condition is `j < len(righthalf)` but your if condition uses `lefthalf[j]`.

When `alist` is odd and `len(alist) = 2N+1`, in a case where `j` goes upto `len(righthalf)-1 = (N+1)-1 = N`, you'd get an index out of range error as `lefthalf[N]` is out of range.

Comment: Thanks again ali,It is working fine now.I forgot to check indexes properly.